# How do I get an input file to read into a string array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, input, getline

For some reason the full lines from my input file are not reading into the array, only the first word in each line. I am currently using the getline call, but I am not sure why it is not working. Here is the what I have for the call to populate the array. The txt file is a list of songs.

```
const int numTracks = 25;
string tracks[numTracks];
int count = 0, results;
string track, END;

cout << "Reading SetList.txt into array" << endl;

ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("SetList.txt");
while (count < numTracks && inputFile >> tracks[count])
{
    count++;
    getline(inputFile, track);
}
inputFile.close();
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `track` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (count < numTracks && inputFile >> tracks[count])
```

The `>>` operator reads a single word. And this code reads this single word into the vector in question.

```
getline(inputFile, track);
```

True, you're using `getline()`. To read the rest of the line, after the initial word, into some unrelated variable called `track`. `track` appears to be a very bored `std::string` that, apparently, gets overwritten on every iteration of the loop, and is otherwise completely ignored.

Comment: Is there anyway to change it so that it reads the full line. I have tried putting in tracks[count] instead of track and I get a catastrophic failure of the program every time.

Comment: Of course there is, but "a catastrophic failure" is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is using the `operator>>` to read the file into the array.  That operator reads one word at a time.  You need to remove that operator completely and use `std::getline()` to fill the array, eg:

```
const int numTracks = 25;
std::string tracks[numTracks];
int count = 0;

std::cout << "Reading SetList.txt into array" << std::endl;

std::ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("SetList.txt");
while (count < numTracks)
{
    if (!std::getline(inputFile, tracks[count])) break;
    count++;
}
inputFile.close();
```

Or:

```
const int numTracks = 25;
std::string tracks[numTracks];
int count = 0;

std::cout << "Reading SetList.txt into array" << std::endl;

std::ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("SetList.txt");
while ((count < numTracks) && (std::getline(inputFile, tracks[count]))
{
    count++;
}
inputFile.close();
```

Alternatively, consider using a `std::vector` instead of a fixed array, then you can use `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter` to get rid of the manual loop completely:

```
class line : public std::string {}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l)
{   
    return std::getline(is, l);
}

...

std::vector<std::string> tracks;

std::cout << "Reading SetList.txt into array" << std::endl;

std::ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("SetList.txt");

std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<line>(inputFile),
    std::istream_iterator<line>(),
    std::back_inserter(tracks)
);

inputFile.close();
```