# How can I put elements of a file into a list?

Tags: c++, list, file

I was investigating, but have not found a lot of information.  Now I'm confused about how to put elements of a file into a list, and how to print the list.

```
std::string line;
std::list<string> l;

//read first file
ifstream myfile("Dataset.1.02.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    getline(myfile, line);
    while (getline(myfile, line) /**/) {
        l.push_back(line);
    }
    myfile.close();
}

for (auto v : l) {
    std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Remove the `getline(myfile, line);` before   `while(getline(myfile,line)/**/){` and the code looks fine to me.

Comment: if you have a problem it probably is that the folder you put your text file is not the right place.

Comment: Consider eliminating the loop altogether by using `std::copy()` with `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter`, eg: [How do I get an input file to read into a string array in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38602530/65863).

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly right. You just need to rearrange your loop to look like this:

```
std::string line;
std::list<std::string> l;

//read first file
std::ifstream myfile ("Dataset.1.02.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()){
    if (getline(myfile, line)) {
        do {
            l.push_back(line);
        } while(getline(myfile, line));
    }
    myfile.close();
}

for (auto v : l){
    std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

The `if` handles the case where the file is empty. Then, once we have a line, we put a line into the list and try to read the next one. If we fail to read a line, we're done.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it fixed your problem, please check the checkmark to the left.